EFI Shell boot loop
I added an NVMe card to an old mainboard and installed pfSense (based on FreeBSD).The BIOS doesn't have drivers for NVMe. According to an Internet tip I installed an EFI shell on a SATA disk, chose that Shell as boot device and started the Clover NVMe driver in startup.nsh. That works. The NVMe drives are now visible and I can start the FreeBSD loader.
But when I starting the FreeBSD loader from startup.nsh a boot loop occurs. After some steps from the pfSense startup process the system resets and begins to boot again.
Any help appreciated, Hans

If the motherboard doesn't support NVMe there's nothing you can do about it, irrespective of some drive being detected or not via the workaround of booting from other drive you found out. It's nor uncommon for motherboards of a certain vintage with M.2 slots to support SATA drives only. Please [edit] the question and add the brand/model of the motherboard.

@ChanganAuto Based on his description, I'm pretty sure he is using a (regular) PCIe to M.2 adapter, or an M.2 slot that does have PCIe wiring (just that it's some "transitional" motherboard that has no NVMe driver in its UEFI firmware).

Based on the previous comment please also clarify exactly what you're using.

System: HP Z620 workstation.

Adapter:
GLOTRENDS PA40 4 Ports M.2 NVMe zu PCIe 3.0 X8 Adapter
As written the system boots the EFI Shell from a SATA HD, starts startup.nsh and loads the NVMe driver.
Afterwards the NVMe SSDs are accessible. When I call manually the FreeBSD EFI Loader the system boots correctly. When I try to include that call in startup.nsh the boot loop occurs.
